# Sorting 2D Array ( String )

Tags: java, jfreechart

I use JFreeChart for this, but I have to change bar color.

[image]

The user wants to change the appearance of the columns.

[image]

I have to change bar color.
Note : I have only a option. ( Price, resolution, brighness e.t.c )

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please look at posting an [MCVE] for quicker help on questions.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117629).